# Trouble with control module .statespace .pzmap

Tags: python, controls

I calculate the zeros and poles of a system with control.StateSpace. In the following I want to use control.pzmap to display the result but the last doesn´t work. I can print sys and it seems okay but not as parameter of control.pzmap.

Can someone pls help me?

```
import numpy as np 
import control
from OMPython import ModelicaSystem
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from help_fkt import delete_OM_files
#from numpy import pi as pi

L=0.1
R=80
C=3.3e-6


A=  [[0,1/C], 
    [-1/L, -R/L]]
B=[[0],[1/L]]

C=[[1,0],[0,1],[-1,0]]

D= [[0],[0],[1]]


print(A)
print(B)
print(C)
print(D)
fig=plt.figure(1, figsize=(10,6)); fig.clf()
plt.show()

sys=control.StateSpace(A,B,C,D)     #calculation of poles and zeros of the given system
print(sys)

a=sys.pole()
print(a)

control.pzmap(sys)                  #should make a diagram of poles and zeros, but doesn't work

plt.grid()
```

This is the error:

> File "C:\anaconda3\envs\modsim\lib\site-packages\control\statesp.py",
> line 575, in zero
> from slycot import ab08nd
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'slycot'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File
> "C:\Users\johan\OneDrive\Desktop\Studium\SimulationundModellbildung\Lösungen\LSG_Carlos\A7.py",
> line 44, in 
> control.pzmap(sys)
>
> File "C:\anaconda3\envs\modsim\lib\site-packages\control\pzmap.py",
> line 91, in pzmap
> zeros = sys.zero()
>
> File
> "C:\anaconda3\envs\modsim\lib\site-packages\control\statesp.py", line
> 587, in zero
> raise NotImplementedError("StateSpace.zero only supports "

NotImplementedError: StateSpace.zero only supports systems with the same number of inputs as outputs.

Error when I try to install slycot:

> (base) C:\Users\johan>pip install slycot                                                                                                                                                                           Collecting slycot                                                                                                                                                                                                    Using cached slycot-0.4.0.0.tar.gz (1.5 MB)                                                                                                                                                                        Installing build dependencies ... done                                                                                                                                                                             Getting requirements to build wheel ... done                                                                                                                                                                         Preparing wheel metadata ... done                                                                                                                                                                              Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from slycot) (1.18.1)                                                                                                                      Building wheels for collected packages: slycot                                                                                                                                                                       Building wheel for slycot (PEP 517) ... error                                                                                                                                                                      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:                                                                                                                                                                      command: 'c:\anaconda3\python.exe' 'c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\pep517_in_process.py' build_wheel 'C:\Users\johan\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpsxxs_crf'                                                      cwd: C:\Users\johan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-r2r2i4rs\slycot                                                                                                                                            Complete output (56 lines):                                                                                                                                                                                        Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.                                                                                                                                                      -- The C compiler identification is unknown                                                                                                                                                                        CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (ENABLE_LANGUAGE):                                                                                                                                                                   The CMAKE_C_COMPILER:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   cl                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     To use the NMake generator with Visual C++, cmake must be run from a shell                                                                                                                                         that can use the compiler cl from the command line.  This environment is                                                                                                                                           unable to invoke the cl compiler.  To fix this problem, run cmake from the                                                                                                                                         Visual Studio Command Prompt (vcvarsall.bat).                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment                                                                                                                                            variable "CC" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_C_COMPILER to the full path to                                                                                                                                        the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!                                                                                                                                                                        See also "C:/Users/johan/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-r2r2i4rs/slycot/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".                                                                                     See also "C:/Users/johan/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-r2r2i4rs/slycot/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".                                                                                      FC ('-DCMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER=', 'c:/anaconda3/Library/bin/flang.exe')                                                                                                                                             F2PY ('-DF2PY_EXECUTABLE=', 'c:/anaconda3/Scripts/f2py.exe')                                                                                                                                                       NUMPY_INCLUDE ('-DNumPy_INCLUDE_DIR=', 'c:/anaconda3/Include')                                                                                                                                                     ['-DSLYCOT_VERSION:STRING=0.4.0', '-DGIT_REVISION:STRING=ac0944b363a6cfcc0c3d5128cdd484d74173aa3b', '-DISRELEASE:STRING=True', '-DFULL_VERSION=0.4.0.gitac0944b', '-GNMake Makefiles', '-DCMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER=c:/anaconda3/Library/bin/flang.exe', '-DF2PY_EXECUTABLE=c:/anaconda3/Scripts/f2py.exe', '-DNumPy_INCLUDE_DIR=c:/anaconda3/Include', '-DCMAKE_Fortran_SIMULATE_VERSION=5.0.0', '-DCMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER_ID=Flang', '-DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE:BOOL=ON']                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        --------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                   -- Trying "NMake Makefiles (Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64 v141)" generator                                                                                                                                           --------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                   ---------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                        ----------------------                                                                                                                                                                                             -----------------                                                                                                                                                                                                  ------------                                                                                                                                                                                                       -------                                                                                                                                                                                                            --                                                                                                                                                                                                                 --                                                                                                                                                                                                                 -------                                                                                                                                                                                                            ------------                                                                                                                                                                                                       -----------------                                                                                                                                                                                                  ----------------------                                                                                                                                                                                             ---------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                        --------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                   -- Trying "NMake Makefiles (Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64 v141)" generator - failure                                                                                                                                 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      ********************************************************************************                                                                                                                                   scikit-build could not get a working generator for your system. Aborting build.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       Building windows wheels for Python 3.7 requires Microsoft Visual Studio 2017.                                                                                                                                      Get it with "Visual Studio 2017":                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              ********************************************************************************                                                                                                                                   ----------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                           ERROR: Failed building wheel for slycot                                                                                                                                                                          Failed to build slycot                                                                                                                                                                                             ERROR: Could not build wheels for slycot which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly                                                                                                                        WARNING: You are using pip version 20.2.4; however, version 20.3.3 is available.                                                                                                                                   You should consider upgrading via the 'c:\anaconda3\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with the library, but it seems that some library is complaining because `slycot` is not installed. try installing it using `pip install slycot` and try again. 

Also verify if your input space has the same number of elements as your output space.

Comment: I tried to install it but it shows another error when I type this command. But it could be this issue. I forgot to say I know from someone else who was able to run this code on his computer without problems.(base) C:\Users\johan>pip install slycot
Collecting slycot
  Using cached slycot-0.4.0.0.tar.gz (1.5 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from slycot) (1.18.1)
Building wheels for collected packages: slycot
  Building...

Comment: Can you please provide the error code you get when trying to install slycot?

Comment: If this is the output you get, then slycot is already installed globally, but you may have to install it in the environment where you are trying to run the code.

Comment: I will edit it in my question post above.

Comment: How to install it in the environment? I am not sure what that means. But I think also like it should be installed.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've installed anaconda environment (just for you ;) ) to pinpoint the problem. It seems thats not just your machine and using the package that you use is a little difficult then trivial.

It seems that you have two problems.

First problem is, one of the packages you use depends on `slycot`. But slycot requires some compiling work on the background in order to install itself. Compiling the files on your pc requires having a compiler installed on your computer. Preferred compiler for this package is `Visual Studio 2017`. If you check the error message carefully, it is asking you to download and install it [from this page](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/).

Second problem is something I am not familiar with. It is complaining that the input space has to be the same size with the output space.

`NotImplementedError: StateSpace.zero only supports systems with the same number of inputs as outputs.`

But then again, this might be caused by the first problem.

So, let's install the VS 2017 first and see if that resolves it. If not, we'll see if anything has changed and proceed from there.